# Android Error meta-data ==> set Navi Bg error

Tags: android, navigationbar

I've an error each time I start the application :

```
02-26 15:14:23.979: E/NavigationBar(7676): meta-data ==> set Navi Bg (package:fr.drinkizy, portResource ID:0, landResource ID:0, alpha:0)
```

The error also happen on Android NavigationDrawer sample app.

**Do you have any idea about this error ?**

*Running on LG-G2 with G2Xposed*

**UPDATE** : Add some come
NavigationDrawer sample app have the same issue : http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

NavigationDrawer Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/background_drawer"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" >

</ListView>
```

I've also tried to remove actionBar Background in my custom style but got the same error

Comment: care to show some code?

Comment: I think it's a G2 Xposed bug because NavigationBar is the software key buttons on the bottom (back, home etc).

Comment: I got this error also by just using LG G2 with original stock ROM without root and Xposed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check that you are not enabling JavaScript under the "onCreate"? it should look something like:

webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

If so - try to remove it, it resolved the same issue that I had. If you can share your code - it will be easier...

Comment: I didn't use any webview or javascript 
the Google NavigationDrawer sample app reproduce the same bug : http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/NavigationDrawer.zip